# Click and scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm having a problem with the offset.top in section fighters. http://jsfiddle.net/sz8YP/1/

Namely, after clicking on the next fighter presses the wheel too far.

```
$(".list-fighters li .toogle").click(function(e) {
    $(".list-fighters li").removeClass("open");
    $(this).parent("li").toggleClass("open");
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top}, 100);
});
```

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: can you please generate a jsFiddle example for us to work with.

Comment: which part on the page do you mean by `wheel`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sz8YP/

Comment: To reproduce: Go to 'fighters' section, on team 1 there are three rows of faces images, click the an image on the first row, it scrolls ok, now click a image on the second row, now it does not scroll well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `scrolltop()` in a timeout, to give the DOM time to update the `offset().top` from your previous call `$(".list-fighters li").removeClass("open");` that modified the height of the page, something like this:

```
var deez = this;
setTimeout(function() {
   $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(deez).offset().top}, 100);
}, 300);
```

After testing, updated to 300ms to catch on height update.

Answer (score 0):

It's all because you have several animations at the same time. Some of them you define with JavaScript and some of them in CSS.

**CSS (main.css:233)**

```
.list-fighters li {
    transition: height 350ms ease;
    -webkit-transition: height 350ms ease;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top}, 100);
```

As you can see you start animation that collapses open fighter description and it takes `350ms` to update it's height. What you need is just wait this amount of time to have proper height of all elements.

```
var that = this;
setTimeout(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(that).offset().top}, 100);
}, 350);
```

Comment: But I have to use this variable to enter the function. Besides it is okay :)